# How to ensure a block of code is executed by not more than n times

Tags: go, synchronization

I would like to place concurrency limit for a piece of code in a goroutine.
I looked at the `mutex`, channels but could not achieve this.

```
m.Lock()
// make request to server
log.Info("Calling server for " + name)
resp, err := netClient.Do(req)
m.Unlock()
log.Info("outside lock for " + name)
```

Using the above code snippet I could restrict the server call one after the other.
Instead is there a way I make this call to be executed by 4 goroutines. Another goroutine can execute it only after any of those 4 responds back.
So at a time I need 4 goroutines inside the block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out curiosity. Why do you want to place limit on concurrency on a piece of code?

Comment: @Peter, Yes this is what I am looking for. I will try to implement this and respond back

Comment: @praveent, The third party library I am calling using the http throws errors beyond a concurrency limit. I am trying various options to handle this and got this question

Comment: thanks for the reply. I believe the answer below is accurate and that should control concurrency in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is a semaphore.
Here is a snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    numOfGoroutines := 4

    sem := make(chan struct{}, numOfGoroutines)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        sem <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            defer func() { <-sem }()
            defer wg.Done()

            fmt.Println(i)
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

This snippet has an important detail that is missing in the link that [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387371/golang-how-do-i-ensure-a-block-of-code-is-executed-by-not-more-than-n-threads-a#comment108596447_61387371) mentioned. The snippet waits for all goroutines to complete before moving forward.

Also, Go implements [a weighted semaphore](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore).